# Submit pig job from oozie

Tags: hive, apache-pig, oozie, oozie-coordinator

I am working on automating Pig jobs using oozie in hadoop cluster.

I was able to run a sample pig script from oozie but my next requirement is to run a pig job where the pig script recieves it's input parameters from a shell script.
Please share your thoughts

Comment: Use a shell action, run your script there, use the capture-output tag and feed that into your pig action.

Comment: Short intro to `<capture_output>` here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32478911/calling-shell-script-in-oozie-how-to-use-decision-node-on-base-of-different-ret/32486550#32486550

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE:**

OK make the original question clear, how can you pass a parameter form a shell script output. Here's the working example:

WORKFLOW.XML

```
<workflow-app xmlns='uri:oozie:workflow:0.3' name='shell-wf'>
    <start to='shell1' />
    <action name='shell1'>
        <shell xmlns="uri:oozie:shell-action:0.1">
            <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
            <configuration>
                <property>
                  <name>mapred.job.queue.name</name>
                  <value>${queueName}</value>
                </property>
            </configuration>
            <exec>so.sh</exec>
            <argument>A</argument>
            <argument>B</argument>
            <file>so.sh</file> 
            <capture-output/>
        </shell>
        <ok to="shell2" />
        <error to="fail" />
    </action>


    <action name='shell2'>
        <shell xmlns="uri:oozie:shell-action:0.1">
            <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
            <configuration>
                <property>
                  <name>mapred.job.queue.name</name>
                  <value>${queueName}</value>
                </property>
            </configuration>
            <exec>so2.sh</exec>
            <argument>${wf:actionData('shell1')['out']}</argument>
            <file>so2.sh</file> 
        </shell>
        <ok to="end" />
        <error to="fail" />
    </action>

    <kill name="fail">
        <message>Script failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
    </kill>
    <end name='end' />
</workflow-app>
```

SO.SH

```
echo "out=test"
```

SO2.SH

```
echo "I'm so2.sh and I get the following param:"
echo $1
```

If you replace the 2nd shell action with your pig action and pass the param to the pig script like this:

```
...
<param>MY_PARAM=${wf:actionData('shell1')['out']}</param>
...
```

Than your original question is solved.

---

**Regarding your sharelib issue**, you have to be sure that in the properties you configured the LIB_PATH=*where/you/jars/are* and hand over this param to the pig action,

```
<param>LIB_PATH=${LIB_PATH}</param>
```

than just register the jars from there:

```
REGISTER '$LIB_PATH/my_jar'
```

==========================================================================
What you are looking for is the

> Map wf:actionData(String node)
>
> This function is only applicable to action nodes that produce output
>   data on completion.
>
> The output data is in a Java Properties format and via this EL
>   function it is available as a Map .

[Documentation](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.2.0-incubating/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#a4.2.2_Basic_EL_Functions)
Here's a nice example: http://www.infoq.com/articles/oozieexample
(actually you have to capture the output as Samson wrote in the comments)

[Some more details](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/DG_ShellActionExtension.html):
"If the capture-output element is present, it indicates Oozie to capture output of the STDOUT of the shell command execution. The Shell command output must be in Java Properties file format and it must not exceed 2KB. From within the workflow definition, the output of an Shell action node is accessible via the String action:output(String node, String key) function (Refer to section '4.2.6 Action EL Functions')."

Or you can use a not so nice but simple work-a-round and execute your shell script in the pig itself and save it's result in a variable, and using that. Like this:

```
%DEFINE MY_VAR `echo "/abc/cba'`
A = LOAD '$MY_VAR' ...
```

But this is not nice at all, the first solution is the suggested.

Comment: Hi
Thanks for the solutions now i have someother requirement where i am using some custom libraries inside the pig scripts. I have placed all the dependent libraries inside /user/oozie/share/lib/ . 
I have a simple pig script and the corresponding shell script to invoke the pig has this content -->  pig -useHCatalogue -f test.pig -p input=table_name;
Now i am trying to call this shell script from oozie shell action. But the job exits with this error : Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.ShellMain], exit code [1]

Comment: I really don't think that's a good idea, let me update my answer and extend it with some more details regarding how to use shell action's captured output

Comment: The reason why i am placing the pig invoke command inside a shell file is because the pig takes too many number of arguments as input like mentioned in previous comment. (example --> input=table_name.) if the above method is not advisable then i will remove the shell action here and would rather go directly to pig action inside oozie. But help me on how to make use of custom jars

Comment: If your oozie share lib configured correctly (check your oozie properties file) than the jars should be accessible from the pig. You just need to register them. As they are placed in the share lib folder you don't need to specify the path.

Comment: Hi kecso,
Thanks for giving clarity on how to pulling in the shell ouput to another node. Above example was very useful.
Can you please help me in running a pigscript using shell script(I don't need any output from shell script) . Just that i am invoking a pigscript using shell script((inside which this command is used : pig -usehcatalog -f sample.pig -p input1=table_1 -p input2=table2). 
This issue the oozie jobs throws error saying "Please initialize HCAT_HOME" 
The same pig script i am able to call directly using pig action.
Where am i going wrong here when using shell action.

Comment: I still not get the point to start the pig script from a shell action. Can you explain it to me?

Comment: Yes, We have a use case where we have 2 pig scripts and the shell script basically invokes the either script1.pig or script2.pig based upon the input arguments given to the shell script. 
To be precise shell script recieves input arguments and decides on how many times and also which pigscript has to be executed , along with decision making it also manipulates the input given to it and these inputs are the ones which are given as parameters to pig call.
These decision making and running a node into loops can not be done using oozie fork(decision node).

Comment: What about the decision node:https://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.2.0-incubating/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#a3.1.4_Decision_Control_Node