# Oozie email action attachment

Tags: shell, hadoop, hdfs, oozie, oozie-coordinator

I am trying to get an hdfs location and provide it as email attachment to oozie email action. My hdfs location can be found only using a shell action. Now how can I pass the output of my shell action, which would be the hdfs path to my oozie email action. Can this be achieved using oozie?

```
<workflow-app name="[WF-DEF-NAME]" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.1">
  ...
  <action name="[NODE-NAME]">
    <email xmlns="uri:oozie:email-action:0.2">
        <to>[COMMA-SEPARATED-TO-ADDRESSES]</to>
        <subject>[SUBJECT]</subject>
        <body>[BODY]</body>
        <content_type>[CONTENT-TYPE]</content_type> 
        **<attachment>[COMMA-SEPARATED-HDFS-FILE-PATHS]</attachment>** 
    </email>
    <ok to="[NODE-NAME]"/>
    <error to="[NODE-NAME]"/>
  </action>
  ...
</workflow-app>
```

Comment: or can i send an hdfs file using bash's mail command, without copying it to local?

Comment: I recently answered a question has to do exactly the same. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34943757/submit-pig-job-from-oozie/34971902#34971902 Check my update on the answer where I attached a working example, how to capture a shell action output and pass it as a parameter of another action node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See my comment, but for others checking this issue, the answer is:
Capture the output of the shell action

```
<capture-output/>
```

and pass it as a param for the email action

```
<attachment>${wf:actionData('shell_action')['path']}</attachment>
```

For detail check the link in my comment.